# To log error lines while inserting data into the postgres table from a text file using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and postgres.
I have a code which reads from a csv file and inserts the data into a table.
The code only works when there are error free lines in the file.
But if there are any errors in some of the lines I want python to ignore those lines and insert the rest of the lines into the table. The lines with the error should be written into a separate file.
The code is as below:

```
import psycopg2
import csv

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' 
    password='postgres'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

cur = conn.cursor()

filehandle = open('abc.csv', 'r') 
reader = csv.reader(filehandle, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    statement = "INSERT INTO abc(col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s')" % (tuple(row))
    cur.execute(statement)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting you use string operations to substitute values into SQL query? **Unlearn it.** If the value would contain `'` (which may easily happen one day), you'd end up with invalid query or even query doing something completely different, because this is the principle of the dreaded SQL injection attack.

Comment: In fact, it's even **easier** to use parameters. Simply: `cur.execute("INSERT ... VALUES (?, ?, ?)", *tuple(row))` should do. That will take care of quoting the values as needed.

Comment: Sorry, for particular case of PostgreSQL it's not `?`, but `%s` (see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

if you detect errors with an exception raised, try this :

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        statement = "INSERT INTO abc(col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s')" % (tuple(row))
        cur.execute(statement)
    except:
        #do the stuff in case of error
```

Comment: **Do not use formatting** to substitute values to SQL, pass the parameters as extra arguments to `execute`. It's faster, even easier and avoids risk of SQL injection attack.